# How to parse XML feed and create Django objects from it

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

is there a good package to parse XML/JSON data and map it to Django model's object fields? The ideal solution would be the one that supports object updates. What can you recommend?

**UPDATE:**

Will tell a bit about my requirements. There affiliate programs that supply partners with content via XML feeds. What I need is to parse the feed time from time and get content out of it and update already existing content (objects).

Comment: Without knowing more information it's difficult to tell if a proposed solution meets your needs. Having said that, take a look at the [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: Specified a bit, hope this helps. Never new that Django Rest Framework is for parsing too.